# How can I create a single ingress for my entire cluster that can automatically use kube-dns for path based routes to internal services?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

My goal is this:

- A single public DNS record for my entire cluster
- A single ingress for my entire cluster
- I don't want to have to update the ingress for new deployments/services- it has a way of automatically routing to them

I'm using gke: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service-discovery

So by default a service gets an internal DNS record like my-svc.my-namespace.svc.my-zone

What I want is to be able to hit that service like this: `http://myapps.com/my-svc.my-namespace.svc.my-zone/someEndpoint`

Is this possible? It would mean I could deploy new deployments and services and they would be immediately be accessible to consumers outside the cluster.

Do you have to associate an ingress with a backend service? I don't want to do that because it means I'll need to update it to add every new deployment/service and I want to make it dynamic. Can you have an ingress use internal DNS for routing to services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are several ways to accomplish this. One way would be to not use the *Ingress* resources at all and instead, put an Nginx proxy in front of your services. Then configure it to proxy all requests. A configuration like this should work.

```
location ~ ^\/(.+?)\/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass http://$1/$2;
}
```

Comment: Not using ingress is the way to go. You might also want to consider using a service mesh to replace ingresses

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best achieved using a combination of nginx proxy and Ingress.

First you create an ingress with your desired host name and add a single backend that points to your nginx proxy.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: youringress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - yourhostname
    secretName: yourtlssecret
  rules:    
  - host: yourhostname
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /your-app-path
        backend:  
          serviceName: nginxservice
          servicePort: nginxserviceport
```

The path value can be a generic slash which will route all the incoming requests to the nginx proxy server first which then forwards it to the respective service based on the path. You wouldn't need to update this ingress everytime you have a new service deployed as its main duty is just to get the request to the nginx proxy server.

Then you create your nginx proxy server with multiple location blocks that routes the requests to the respective services in your cluster based on the kube-dns names.

```
server {
        listen       1080;
        server_name  localhost $hostname;

        location /path-to-the-service1 {
           proxy_pass http://name-of-service1
        }

        location /path-to-the-service2 {
           proxy_pass http://name-of-service2
        }

        location /path-to-the-service3 {
           proxy_pass http://name-of-service3
        }
    }
```

In your cluster if you create a service with the name say frontendservice, the nginx proxy server can reach it using the kube-dns name

```
location /path-to-the-frontendservice {
               proxy_pass http://frontendservice
            }
```

You can keep adding up your new deployments as a separate location block in the nginx proxy server which will take care of the routing for you.

You should then be able to hit any service using your url like

http://my-app-url/path-to-the-service/